# How do I interface an ASIC with a PCI interface to an embedded microprocessor?

Tags: embedded, pci, microprocessors

I have an ASIC that has a PCI interface that I need to use in an embedded project I'm working on.  The microprocessor I am considering right now is a Freescale MPC5668G, which has I2C, SPI, DMA, Media Local Bus interfaces.  The MPC5668G is necessary because the project requires multiple CAN buses.

The issue is that I don't have any experience with PCI and I'm not sure what the best way to interface between the ASIC and the microprocessor.

Can anyone provide some insight on where to start?

Thank you,

Andy

Comment: That's probably going to be ugly.  You could either look at trying to find a localbus<>PCI bridge chip that you could drive using GPIOs, or you could try to emulate enough of PCI locally to do it, or you could try to build some sort of custom bridge in an FPGA using something like SPI as a backend.  Are you sure there are no alternatives to that legacy ASIC?  What about using a small embedded computer that might be able to do PCI via some PCIe bridge, and add a dual CAN peripheral to it?

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'm glad I wasn't completely crazy for thinking this may be ugly.  The local bus options looks like the most reasonable without changing microprocessors, but a processor with a PCI interface built in may be the best solution.

Comment: This question is too broad for the format of Stack Overflow. That being said, as someone with plenty of experience from Freescale MCUs, I would _strongly recommend_ that you contact Freescale and ask them for the full source code in C of the FlexCAN driver. Otherwise you'll end up writing it yourself, which is approximately 1-2 months of extra work. Been there, done that. I very much doubt Freescale has improved since I last started a MPC56 project, but who knows. If they still can't provide you with the driver, tell them to get lost and use an ARM Cortex instead.